# Views Distinct Option in Drupal 7

Tags: distinct, drupal-views

I am using Drupal 7. I have created the view which will be filtered by their taxonomy terms, If more than one node choose the same taxonomy term, the view is repeated the taxonomy term values. How to avoid the repeated values in the views and showing only latest node which will be created from the taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the filter criteria, you choose "Content: Has taxonomy term:", after that you choose your taxonomy, and on the third step there is a field "Reduce duplicates", if you check it, the view shouldn't show twice the same node.[image]